# Angular - Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}' with AoT compilation

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error ERROR in ng:... template.html: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}' when compiling using Angular Cli >  ng build --prod --aot

Form template:

```
        <form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">

            <input [(ngModel)]="user.email" id="email"
                   type="email" class="validate" name="email" required>
            <label for="email">Email</label>

            ...

        </form>
```

LoginComponent:

```
export class LoginComponent {

    public user = {};
    public errorMsg = '';
    email: any;
    password: any;

constructor(
...
) {
```

Adding a type email:string or email:any in the form's component does not do the trick. It seems to be referring to a factory Angular component {}. How can I get around this error ?

Comment: Where is the code of your component? Have you read the code? The `email` field you're using is on the `user` field of the component. Not on the component.

Comment: Where and how is a value assigned to `user`?

Comment: I guess this should help user: any = {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public user = {};
```

This user object doesn't have any property named email. Change it to

```
public user = { email: '' };
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem come from the user instantiation.

The following instantiation should work :

```
public user = {'email': ''}
```

But a similar error may happen for the password (depending how you use it in the template).

In that case the instantiation should be :

```
public user = {'email': '',
               'password': ''
              }
```

A better way is to create a user class. The user.ts should be like following :

```
export class User {

    constructor(public email?: string,
                public password?: string) { }

}
```

and then instantiate the user in your LoginComponent like this :

```
public user: User = new User();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can assign a type of object.

```
public user = <{email: string}>{};
```